# Can DQN perform better than Double DQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-rl, double-dqn

I'm training both DQN and double DQN in the same environment, but DQN performs significantly better than double DQN. As I've seen [in the double DQN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf), double DQN should perform better than DQN. Am I doing something wrong or is it possible?

Comment: Hello. I am facing the same issue. What explanation finally did you give ?

Comment: I have the same result, DQN performs better than Double DQN. I m try to understand why.

Comment: DDQN was designed to address Q-function overestimation. So it is possible that your DQN which performs "better" is just a red herring where Q learnt is bogus and over-optimistic. So when DDQN produces lower numbers it only looks "worse" but in fact is closer to realistic solution.. Just a thought..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no thorough proof, theoretical or experimental that Double DQN is better then vanilla DQN. There are a lot of different tasks, paper and later experiments only explore some of them. What practitioner can take out of it is that *on some tasks* DDQN is better. That's the essence of Deep Mind's "Rainbow" approach - drop a lot of different methods into bucket and take best results.

Comment: Can you give some references where DQN outperforms DoubleDQN?

Comment: I have a problem where my DQN is better than DoubleDQN and I cannot give a valid explanation on why.

Answer (score 1):

That may happen when the value of the state is bad. You can find the example and explain about that in the link below.

See this:https://medium.freecodecamp.org/improvements-in-deep-q-learning-dueling-double-dqn-prioritized-experience-replay-and-fixed-58b130cc5682

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of the state is bad"? As I'm using an OpenAI-Gym environment, the value of the state is just the observation that I'm getting from it.

Comment: @Angelo  you can read the blog above to understand the answer . As you calculate all actions at one state but all these actions  do not affect the environment in a relevant way.

Comment: @Angelo In most states, the choice of action has no effect.

Comment: We prefer answers that contain the necessary info to answer the question, rather than answers that just link to another external resource, so I suggest that you provide the necessary info from that article in your answer.

Comment: In your link, it says that in DuelingDQN session, not in DoubleDQN as asked.

Comment: @ddaedalus It has both of them and you can see this: https://medium.com/@parsa_h_m/deep-reinforcement-learning-dqn-double-dqn-dueling-dqn-noisy-dqn-and-dqn-with-prioritized-551f621a9823