# Can DQN outperform DoubleDQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl, reference-request, double-dqn

I found a similar [post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/can-dqn-perform-better-than-double-dqn) about this issue, but unfortunately I did not find a proper answer. Are there any references where DQN is better than DoubleDQN, that is DoubleDQN does not improve DQN ?

Comment: This indeed seems to be a duplicate of the other question, although maybe not an exact duplicate because you're also asking for references, so I will leave it open.